# How attachements removed automatically when uninstall custom module in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo

I have custom module - MyModule
i have attached files with this module via ir.attachment model.
When i uninstalled MyModule but the attachments remains linked to custom records.
How attachments will be automatically removed when uninstall custom module linked to ir.attached model  ?

Comment: How did you create the attachments? Directly in code (so on installation or upgrade) or otherwise?

Comment: I use this coding approach as done in PROJECT Module
@api.multi
def attachment_tree_view(self):
     self.ensure_one()
     domain = [ 
     '&', ('res_model', '=', 'res.partner'), ('res_id', 'in', self.ids)]
     return {
     'name': 'Attachments',
    'domain': domain,
    'res_model': 'ir.attachment',
   'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
   'view_id': False,
   'view_mode': 'kanban,tree,form',
   'view_type': 'form',
   'help': ('''<p>Message</p>'''),
   'limit': 80,
   'context': "{'default_res_model': '%s','default_res_id': %d}" % (self._name, self.id)}